# What is the correct way to import vuetify's directives?

Tags: vuetify.js

What is the correct way to import vuetify's built-in directives ? Like [this one](https://vuetifyjs.com/directives/resizing).

I'm doing this, which works but seems kinda crappy:

```
import { Vuetify, VApp, VNavigationDrawer, VProgressLinear, VList, VBtn, VIcon, VGrid, VToolbar } from 'vuetify';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/es5/directives';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: { VApp, VNavigationDrawer, VProgressLinear, VList, VBtn, VIcon, VGrid, VToolbar },
  directives,
  theme: {
    ...
  }
});
```

Later in my `.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div v-resize="resize">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      resize() {
        ...
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Note: the accepted answer is for Vuetify 1, for Vuetify 2 see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clean solution if you want only **Resize** directive

```
import { Resize } from 'vuetify/es5/directives';
```

and simply :

```
export default {
 ....
  directives : {
     Resize
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is for Vuetify 1, for Vuetify 2 you shoud use:

```
import { Resize } from 'vuetify/lib/directives';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  directives: {
    Resize
  }
});
```